# Was there manipulation of racism in the Vietnam war?

Tags: united-states, war, propaganda, vietnam

It is fairly well established that racism was taken advantage of by both sides during WW2, especially (from the American perspective) in the Pacific theater (see for example “[War without mercy: Race and Power in the Pacific War](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0394751728)", or [this web page](https://artifactsjournal.missouri.edu/2012/03/wwii-propaganda-the-influence-of-racism/), or [Dr. Seuss](http://www.tofugu.com/2013/02/20/dr-seuss/)).

Was there a similar manipulation of racism during the Vietnam war?

Comment: What topics can I ask about here? History Stack Exchange is for historians and history buffs. If you have a question about: It is not about: Genealogy, **Asking for reference material**, Questions answered by a simple Google search or to be found in a Wikipedia page, Predicting the future based on historical trends, Mythology, General (non-human) Prehistory, Conspiracy Theories or Pseudo-science.

From: http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Furthermore, your question is not very clear. Are you asking about US propaganda against the Viet Cong, Vietnamese people or communism in Asia?

Comment: Tried to edit the question to keep it within guidelines. Presumably a reasonable answer will cite references that @Le Douglerino could use.

Comment: I'm not sure what "manipulation of racism" is, but this edit resolves the fundamental problems with the prior question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - I used "manipulation of racism" to mean taking advantage of existing biases/racism endemic in a society to promote the propagandist agenda. Tried to use neutral wording to keep this from being  US-centric.

Comment: @T.E.D. - Added in some more references other than the original questioner's to give context

Comment: This is more about Politics.stackexchange.com than history.

Comment: @Doug B: If you're asking about just the US, no, there wasn't (going by my memory) any sort of racial propaganda.  Indeed, it's hard to see how there could be, since (in the official view at the time: let's not argue about whether or not it was correct) the US was supporting South Vietnam against the North Vietnamese Communists and their (mostly Caucasian) Soviet Communist puppet masters.

Comment: I highly doubt [Hanoi Hannah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanoi_Hannah) avoided the subject.

Comment: FWIW: I like the current edit. Is it good enough to reopen yet?